# Validação com método clean no Django 2.0

Tags: django

No meu Model tem esse método abaixo:

```
def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        valortotal = Venda.objects.filter(id=self.id).aggregate(valortotal=Sum(F('item__produto__valor') * F('item__qtde'), output_field=FloatField()))
        valor_nota = self.valor_nota
        if Decimal(valortotal['valortotal']) < valor_nota():
         raise forms.ValidationError("O  valor do Tipo de Pagamento (dinheiro + cartão) não pode ser maior que o valor total da nota.")
        #raise forms.ValidationError(Decimal(valortotal['valortotal']))
```

Mais ao salvar o sistema aparece o erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe alguma solução para isso.

Comment: A mensagem diz que nao pode converter um `None` para um valor decimal, provavelmente  no seu if `if Decimal(valortotal['valortotal']) < valor_nota():` o `valortotal['valortotal']` está retornando `None`.

Comment: Mais o estranho que tenho um método parecido que da certo no template: def valortotal(self):
        soma = Venda.objects.filter(id=self.id).aggregate(valortotal=Sum(F('item__produto__valor') * F('item__qtde'), output_field=FloatField()))
        return soma['valortotal']

Comment: Porque nesse metodo não tem retorno invalido, coloque uma linha antes do if assim: `valor_total = valortotal['valortotal'] if valortotal['valortotal']  is not None else 0` e altere seu if para: `if Decimal(valor_total) < valor_nota():` e veja o que acontece.